# No definitions for Kindle Fire devices available in Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, kindle-fire

I want to create AVD for KindleFire but I have some difficulties. According to every site I can find on the web regarding the problem, after performing these steps:

1. In eclipse go to Windows --> Android SDK Manager click to open it.
2. Then it will open the sdk manager then on the top two menus are listed one for Packages and other for Tools.
3. Then open the tools menu click Manage Add-on Sites. Click the User Defined Sites tab, and then click New.
4. In the Add Add-on Site URL dialog box, enter the following URL: http://kindle-sdk.s3.amazonaws.com/addon.xml Click OK, and then click Close. Wait for the Android SDK Manager to refresh.

I should be able to to choose and install Kindle Fire Device Definitions and then their images (see here for example: https://developer.amazon.com/post/Tx3RZFBU0KJTSWS/Setting-up-the-ADB-driver-for-Kindle-Fire-Devices.html )

However, the only thing that is present on the list is Kindle Fire USB Driver. 
I have installed many other packages hoping that they will maybe "unlock" the other downloads but nothing helps. Are the images no longer available? Or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have dropped supporting emulators.

https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=479

scroll to the bottom for the great news.  I guess you just have to deploy it to your device to test it out.

There is another option.  Which won't work for things like the amazon mobile sdk, but anyway, you can create a device in the device manager and give it the same specs as the device you are targeting.  This will at least give you some idea bout layout and such.  It may help to do this.

Comment: yeah it took me some time to find it out, too :(